# Correct use of the word 'through'?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, synonyms

I always had a doubt using the word *through*; basically I would like to say this sentence:

> Thanks Alex for all the money saved **through** your tips.

Is the use of the word *through* correct in this sentence?

**NOTE:** I want to keep the sentence unchanged; if there's anything to be corrected, it must only be the word *through*.

Comment: This one needs a native speaker's or a very experienced ear... I tried to search for usage in Google Books, but there seem to be to many variables for a definite conclusion (IMO). (Another concern: I' not quite sure, but I'd say that "Alex" should be enclosed in commas).

Comment: Yes, if you are talking to Alex directly, then there should be a comma before and after Alex: *Thanks, Alex, for all the money saved through your tips.*

Comment: I've got no problem with *through* but I'd probably choose *by using* or *by following* myself, because only by actually *doing* what the tips suggest can you save some money; the tips themselves are just suggestions and one must  actually *follow* a suggestion to receive benefit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ciao, Federico

You have used *[through](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/through)* (definition 5, *by means of*) correctly in your sentence. Good job.

I will say that it is not all that natural. In other words, it's grammatical and understandable, but not idiomatic, not the most natural way to express the thought.

*Through* is often used as a result of a middleman, or to signify a process. Neither of these apply to *your tips*.

Also, are you thanking Alex directly? If so, you need commas before and after Alex:

> Thanks, Alex, for all the money saved through your tips.

In addition, *[tips](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/tip?q=Tips#tip-3)* is ambiguous without further context, as the word can mean either (monetary) *tips* gained from working as a waiter, for example, or *tips* as in *suggestions*. I assume you mean the latter, and in any case it does not much affect the choice of preposition.

Changing no word except *through*, the following are perhaps preferable:

> Thanks, Alex, for all the money saved from your tips.

and

> Thanks, Alex, for all the money saved by your tips.

But, frankly, two more natural sentences are

> Thanks, Alex, for all the money you (have) saved me by (means of) your tips.

and

> Thanks, Alex, for all the money I (have) saved from/by (using/following) your tips.

Just as many native speakers would not normally choose the  preposition *through* in either of these two sentences, we wouldn't normally choose it in your original sentence. There is no explanation as to *Why*, rather it's simply a matter of being familiar with which preposition sounds better, or "works" more naturally in a particular sentence.

I am a native speaker of American English.

Answer (score 5):

I think your sentence is correct. One of the meanings of the word *through* is *as a result of*. See the [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/through).

Comment: are you native speaker?

Comment: @FedericoGentile Since he has not replied, I will say, as a native speaker, that the sentence sounds fully natural (with the commas, as suggested in a comment by @pazzo) and Alex's explanation is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I had a look *through* this post and found that a correct use was given *through* your example.

Essentially `through` is appropriate when you want to convey:

> some kind of effect occurred **through or via the method of** some kind of cause.

The difference between `through` and `because` is that through implies that the action was required to produce the effect, where as because of only implies a reason.  Compare:

- I drove the nail in to a piece of wood *through* careful use of a hammer.
- I covered my ears *because* the fire alarm was very loud.

The alternative suggestions are of varying help...

`From` would only be the correct construction if you were implying you collected the money as with the sheep here:

- This morning I gathered the sheep *from* the field.

`By following` or `by using` isn't too bad, but there's a subtle difference.  Constructing a sentence using one of these forms implies that the result of the action was final rather than part of a sequence of steps.

- I reached my destination *by following* the signs.
- I reached my destination *by using* public transport.
- I reached my destination *through* the forest path.

I personally feel that only the third one implies that it is describing only part of how I got there, where as the other two imply that this was the only major part of the journey.  In the case of your sentence, `by following` implies that the tips were complete instructions and that following them is all that is necessary, while `through` implies that the tips need to be understood and adjusted to fit the circumstances.

It is also appropriate when something is moving within something else, such as:

- I walked *through* the room.
- The room was lit by the sun coming *through* the window.

Edit: Also, because you asked Pazzo, yes I'm a native speaker.  Pazzo is also correct that there should be commas around "Alex" in your sentence.

Edit 2: I just noticed you asked Alex S, not Pazzo, oops.